# Detect if model is being created or updated inside a method

Tags: php, laravel

In my **BaseModel** which extends **Eloquent** I have the **validate** method.

My question is, how can I detect inside this method if the model is being created or updated?

I'm aware and I use the model events, but can't figure out how to achieve the same inside methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could see if the attributes are already set in that model using `getOriginal()`.

Depending on what you get, you can know if it's a new model or an existing one.

---

`getOriginal()` docs:

http://laravel.com/api/source-class-Illuminate.Database.Eloquent.Model.html#2114-2124

Answer (score 1):

Laravel has a method called `exists()` to check whether a model is from database or not.

if Model created or updated, the following will return true.

```
$model->exists
```

**update a model:**

```
$affectedRows = User::where('votes', '>', 100)->update(array('status' => 2));

dd($affectedRows);
```

**Reference:**

http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#insert-update-delete

Comment: Well before validation do as he says... `$this->exists()` will be true or false.

Comment: Ok, I must be doing something wrong, always returns true for me.